# JavaScript: toPrecision inconsistency

Tags: javascript

Why is JavaScript's `toPrecision` method sometimes rounding up and sometimes down?

For example:

```js
console.log("1.05.toPrecision(2) = " + (1.05).toPrecision(2)); // returns "1.1"
console.log("1.005.toPrecision(3) = " + (1.005).toPrecision(3)); // returns "1.00", shouldn't it be "1.01"?
```

Note: I noticed this behavior on all browsers except of IE (tested on IE 11).

Comment: This seems to be a floating point error. I noticed it happens in Swift too, not just JavaScript. In Swift, 1.005 is represented as 1.0049999999999999, so I would assume it has something to do with the amount of digits reserved for the exponent.

Comment: @rid good point, actually it happens in Python too, funny though that IE 11 is immune to this :)

Comment: Check this too : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18358056/5830872